# Typescript component selector should be named undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, yarnpkg, tslint

In my angular application, I have a component which is referred to by the html of another component, so I gave it a selector in kebab case as follows:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'swiftlog-navbar',
  templateUrl: './swiftlog-navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./swiftlog-navbar.component.css']
})
export class SwiftlogNavbarComponent {
```

When I run yarn start I get the following error

> WARNING in ./src/main/webapp/app/swiftlog-navbar/swiftlog-navbar.component.ts
>   [4, 13]: The selector of the component "SwiftlogNavbarComponent" should be named undefined (https://angular.io/styleguide#style-05-02)'

Any ideas what is meant by "should be named undefined", which rule in the tslint file is being applied here, or what I am doing wrong?  I can't find any clues in the styleguide quoted above.

Thanks, Mart

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using angular-cli try to add your own prefix to the angular-cli.json:

```
apps: [
  {  ..., "prefix": "swiftlog"}
]
```

also change your tslint config:

```
"component-selector": [true, "element", "swiftlog", "kebab-case"],
```

[here](https://github.com/angular/devkit/blob/7fce9ccece3de26de0e8f06667aefbcf8080f97d/packages/schematics/angular/application/files/tslint.json#L126) the reference to this config property.

Comment: And why is this needed? how dos this fix the issue? explain please.

Comment: In my opinion it shouldn't be needed. I think @Martin Bamford can have some issue with tslint config. But [this](https://angular.io/api/core/CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA) can also fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks, but I added the above code and I still got the warning unfortunately.  I am trying to understand what is meant by the warning and what rule in tslint config is causing it

Comment: I updated the answer, probably in your case it is a tslint issue